# Why this method returns "null" but not null

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this method which extracts some info from  `remittanceInformation` object

```
private static String combineStrings(RemittanceInformation remittanceInformation) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(remittanceInformation)
                .map(RemittanceInformation::getUstrds)
                .map(l -> l.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(/* CRLF? */)))
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

Now everything inside `remittanceInformation` is `null` and the method in this case should return `null`
but it returns `"null"` with double quotes, Why this behavior ?

Comment: *everything inside remittanceInformation is `null`* is not same as `remittanceInformation == null`, right? and it certainly doesn't mean `getUstrds==null` either in your case, if you can confirm... then compare your code with `Stream.of(null, "").collect(Collectors.joining(/* CRLF? */)`

Comment: **Unable to reproduce:** [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/zpRXJ3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joining of strings delivers a string, possible "null" (""+null) if there is one term being null. That must be the case: a non-null remittanceInformation where getUstrds() gives a collection with a single null.

Comment: OP said *"everything inside remittanceInformation is null"*, so `getUstrds()` returns `null`, which means that the second `map(...)` is not called.

Comment: I reviewed the remittanceInformation carefully and found that getUstrds() returns a list with only one element and that element is set to null

Comment: _"Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."_